# Django test if the variable is numeric

Tags: django

Looks like a question that should be already covered, but after spending some time, I did not find how to check that a variable is numeric in Django template.
Something like

```
{% if my_var.isnumeric %}
    # do something
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE**
As I learnt from the below discussion, there seems to be no built-in tag to check this, and we end up having to create our own template tag.

Comment: You could make your own template tag, but chances are this would just be covering up some shady logic, why wouldn't it be a number?

Comment: Yeap, I've already mastered the technique of user-defined template tags. The question is, whether there's a built-in tag

Comment: The question is, why would you need it? why *wouldn't* it be a number?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan define "numeric" - integers only, or floats as well? What about scientific notation `11E3 == 11000.0`?

Comment: Yes, scientific notation should be recognized as well. Effectively, I am looking for Jquery's $.isNumeric analogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "numeric" means "contains only digits" (and no decimal point, no minus sign, etc.)

Custom filter is your best bet:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def is_numberic(value):
    return "{}".format(value).isdigit()
```

Docs about custom template filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Usage in templates:

```
{% load your_custom_lib %}
...
{% if something|is_numberic %}...
```

---

If you consider integers as numeric (positive and negative), then the function becomes:

```
try:
    int("{}".format(value))
except ValueError:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

In case "numeric" means "integer or float", then use `float` instead of `int`. But note that this will also recognize `-12E3` as numeric, because:

```
>>> -12E3
-12000.0
```

Comment: Emm, @frnhr, I DO assume that "numeric" can contain decimal points, minus sign, etc. And I wan't looking for customized solution. The question was to make sure that there's no built-in shortcut and I won't reinvent a wheel :)

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan There isn't a built-in solution AFAIK, so we are not reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

```
{{ value|divisibleby:"1" }}
```

EDIT: Nope, raises an exception if a string is given.

Comment: The code behind this filter is: `return int(value) % int(arg) == 0`, so it might raise exceptions like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'something'` . I _think_, haven't tested it.

Comment: Yep, I tested it and it raises an exception with a string.